# Диалоговое окно (Нажал нет)

Tags: c#, winforms

Появляется диалоговое окно с кнопками Yes и No

```
var close = MessageBox.Show("Вы точно хотите закрыть файл?", "Закрытие", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
if (close == DialogResult.Yes)
{
    Exit();
}
if (close == DialogResult.No)
{
    //Чтобы тут такого написать, чтобы программа продолжила работу ?
}
```

Поскольку по умолчанию, независимо что ты нажмешь, произойдет условие что нажата кнопка Yes.

Comment: ничего не пиши, убей эту проверку вообще

Comment: В каком месте выполняется этот код? Вероятно, в обработчике закрытия формы? Отредактируйте вопрос, добавив информации.

Comment: Хорошо, здесь такое сработало. Есть другая проблема. Когда я пытаюсь закрыть форму. Я делаю точно такое же условие, но если нажму нет оно просто завершает программу, как сделать событие ожидания каких нибудь дальнейших действий от пользователя ?

Comment: @user209821 дополнительные вопросы надо задавать именно как вопросы, а не в комментариях

Answer (score 1):

```
e.Cansel = MessageBox.Show
(
  "Вы точно хотите закрыть файл?",
  "Закрытие",
  MessageBoxButtons.YesNo
) == DialogResult.No;
```

Comment: А можно избавиться от горизонтального переполнения? Ну позязя!

Comment: @VladD, 116 символов влазиют в половину ширины стандартного экрана. Если SO поменяет дизайн, скролла не будет)))

Comment: @VladD, избавился. Хотя в коде не хотел бы я такое оформление увидеть.

Comment: Ага, я тоже такое форматирование как-то не очень. Я бы отформатировал так: http://pastebin.com/2zZwZwA3 (заодно отделил логику messagebox'а от логики cancellation'а).

Comment: Хотя да, у меня в коде граница стоит на 120 символах :) При копировании на SO приходится переформатировать.

Comment: @VladD, не люблю бесполезные промежуточные переменные.

Comment: Правда? Мне они почему-то нравятся. Ну, вопрос персонального стиля, да.